# Socket exception while running client windows application form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sockets

I have main window application form written in C# which has two option:

- build server
- build client

Both are build new window form after enter ipaddress and port with different behaviour. Client application run without problem with another server (server run independly). When I run server from this main form Client return:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005)

My server is multithread and this is method which run server:

```
  public int Server()
  {
      this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
      this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
      this.listenThread.Start();
      this.listenThread.Join();
      return 0;
  }
```

It's run without exception in windows console application. When I try this code with windows form application it does not work and return exception as I write above.

Comment: Why do you `Start` then `Join`? You are essentially turning a multi-threaded application into a single threaded one.

Comment: Also if you really need asynchronous accepting of clients, using `Socket` class's `BeginAccept` is a better way than to create threads manually.

Comment: We'll need the code of the `ListenForClients` method to be able to help.